# Video/mp4 not loading using Webpack, Laravel Mix in Laravel 8 & reactjs

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

I'm new to Laravel and I'm trying to compile and upload my resources of video using Laravel Mix.

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .react()
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

And this is the code frontend with the react

```
import React from 'react';
import Video from '../../videos/video.mp4';
import {HeroContainer, HeroBg, VideoBg} from './HeroElements';

const HeroSection = () => {
    return (
        <HeroContainer id="home">
            <HeroBg>
                <VideoBg autoPlay loop muted src={Video} type='video/mp4' />
            </HeroBg>
        </HeroContainer>
    )
}

export default HeroSection;
```

And this is the result of the output and error

> Module parse failed: Unexpected character ' ' (1:0)
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> (Source code omitted for this binary file)

Comment: It's saying you can't load a video with `import` without an appropriate loader and I don't think it's a wise idea to load the video this way.

Comment: And how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are experiencing the error in the screenshot below, try the following:

1. Install the [raw_loader](https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/raw-loader/) module:

```
npm install raw-loader --save-dev
```

2. In the `webpack.mix.js` file use the `raw_loader` module in a rule that captures the files you want:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
mix.webpackConfig({ module: { rules: [{ test: /\.mp4$/i, use: 'raw-loader' }] } })
   .ts('resources/ts/app.ts', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

---

For the regular expression to capture more file you can use it as:

```
/\.(mp4|avi|pdf|mp3)$/i
```

---

The error that occurred before using the `raw_loader` module:

[image: laravel mix with webpack error]

Success using `raw_loader` module:

[image: laravel mix with webpack and raw_loader module]

---

*Ps: Looks like you're using React. In my example I used Vue.Js 3... but the problem doesn't seem to relate to that.*